# Delay between displaying an input value in react

Tags: forms, reactjs, input, numbers, redux

what I'm trying to fix is the one-key-delay in the state update with the e.target.value.

I have tried solving it without redux and I have the exact same problem.

http://codepen.io/yoloonthebf/pen/Kmwrpq?editors=0010

Thanks a lot for you help, I hope that you can understand from my pen the issue.

```
class App extends React.Component{ 
  //here is the issue ?!
  handleChange(e){

    const BACKSPACE_KEYCODE = 8;
    const keyCodeIn = e.keyCode;
    if ( !isNumber(keyCodeIn) && !(keyCodeIn === BACKSPACE_KEYCODE) ) {
      return e.preventDefault();
    }else{
      store.dispatch({type: 'UPDATE', payload: e.target.value});
    }
    function isNumber(keyCode){
      return (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105)
    }
    console.log(store.getState())
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>{store.getState()}</h1>
        <input 
          type='text' 
          className='form-control' 
          maxLength='16'
          onKeyDown={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Edit:
I forgot to mention I only need numbers, 16 of them to be exact, I want to build a Credit Card Validation tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your `onKeyDown` event. The `e.target.value` is filled after a `onKeyUp` event, not after a `onKeyDown`. You should use the `onChange` event :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmPrNz?editors=0010

I hope it will fit your needs

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I forgot to mention I only need numbers, 16 of them to be exact, I want to build a Credit Card Validation tool.

Comment: I updated my answer with a new CodePen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmPrNz?editors=0010

Comment: thanks a lot buddy, you really helped me with this one